# How can I find Pydantic's Basemodel field value by a STRING?

Tags: python, pydantic

For example I have a pydantic model, like this:

```
class Person:
   name:str
   age: int
   city: str
```

With pydantic we can get the value by using: `P1.name` -for example P1 already exists as an **instance**-
My question is that I have a P1 and I have a **string**.

```
P1 = People[name='Steve', age=22, city='New York']
data = "city"
```

How can I get the field named city with that data string, which will return New York?

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    res = getattr(P1, data)
except AttributeError:
    # no such attribute for p1
    res = None
print(f"{res=}")
```

Comment: This can just be `res = getattr(P1, data, None)`